# Binary Expression Tree Evaluation

Tags: c++

I want to evaluate a binary expression tree. This is the code that I have mustered so far. I am destroying nodes of the tree as I evaluate it. But the problem is that during recursion it looks for a data that it doesn't have, I think. It simply keeps on returning 0.

```
void calc(bnode *&b)
{
    bnode *c;
    int m;
    switch (b->data.ch)
    {
        case '+':m=b->lchild->data.in+b->rchild->data.in;
                 break;
        case '-':m=b->rchild->data.in-b->lchild->data.in;
                 break;
        case '*':m=b->lchild->data.in*b->rchild->data.in;
                 break;
        case '/':m=b->lchild->data.in/b->rchild->data.in;
                 break;
        case '%':m=b->lchild->data.in%b->rchild->data.in;
                 break;
    }

     c=new(bnode);
     c->lchild=NULL;
     c->rchild=NULL;
     c->tag=1;
     c->data.in=m;
     b=c;
}

int eval(bnode *b)
{
    if (b->tag==1)
    return b->data.in;
    else
    {
        if (b->lchild->tag==0)
           eval(b->lchild);
        if (b->rchild->tag==0)
           eval(b->rchild);
        if (b->lchild->tag==1&&b->rchild->tag==1)
           calc(b);
    }
}
```

And the structure I used is

```
union un
{
    int in;
    char ch;
};

struct bnode{
    bnode *lchild;
    un data;
    int tag;
    bnode *rchild;
};
```

Comment: Could you give more details on what happen.

Answer (score 2):

The function `eval()` is broken. In the "else" branch, you never return any value, which is undefined behavior.

[Edit] The eval function should be changed to something like this.

```
int eval(bnode *b)
{
    if (b->lchild && b->lchild->tag == 0)
        eval(b->lchild);
    if (b->rchild && b->rchild->tag == 0)
        eval(b->rchild);
    if (b->lchild && b->rchild && b->lchild->tag == 1 && b->rchild->tag == 1)
        calc(b);

    if (b->tag == 1)
        return b->data.in;
    else
        throw "Evaluation error";
}
```

You also have memory leaks, because the `bnode` objects are never deleted.

Comment: So what would should be done. I don't know what to return there. Should I return 0?

Comment: You'll have to decide on the required behavior yourself, I'm afraid